Почему channels выделяется как Unexpected argument. get_channels_for_subscribe(clients[:2]) возвращает список
Почему channels выделяется как Unexpected argument. get_channels_for_subscribe(clients[:2]) возвращает список.

так ругается у вас функция join_groups. смотрите в описании, что эта функция требует на вход.

def join_groups(
tg_clients: list[TelegramClient],
chats_list: list[dict]
) -> None:
